# Unwrapping a cylinder onto a plane

Tags: projection, cylindrical-coordinates

I have an image of a label on a bottle, and I need to 'unwrap' the image as if I had taken the label off of the bottle and laid it flat on a table.

Is there an easy way to transform the image, given the properties of the cylinder are known, and the distance between the cylinder and the plane?

Comment: I take it the image is in 3d co-ordinates and you want to transfer it onto 2d co-ordinates?  Do you have freedom to define the axis of the bottle or is it given?

Comment: Yes, you are entirely correct. Also, the axis of the bottle can be freely defined.

Comment: Not something I have any experience of but if we choose $(0,r,z)$ as the axis of the bottle, the bottle has radius $r$ and height $h$ and its base sits at $x=0$ then supposing you want to send the rectangle to the $xz$ plane, then you can cut the label at $(0,0,z)$ and leave one end $(0,0,z)$ where it is, while sending the other end $(0,0,z)$ to $(2\pi r,0,z)$

Comment: Then to achieve this you just need to send polar co-ordinates around the axis $(0,r,z)$ to the space between $(0,0,z)$ and $(2\pi r,0,z)$  This is probably easiest achieved by representing the $xy$ plane as $\Bbb C$

Comment: You basically have to back-project the image of the label onto the cylinder, after which you can “unwrap” it as suggested by @RobertFrost. To do the former, you’ll need to know (or deduce) some things about the camera. What information do you have about the camera and/or the image, e.g., actual dimensions of the label and bottle?

Comment: I know the actual dimensions of the label and bottle, the bottle radius, the distance of the camera focal point to the bottle.

One thing making it slightly trickier is that the camera to project on is at a slight angle looking slightly down, meaning that I need to project onto a slightly angled plane also. Maybe this is a two step process: correct for the plane offset, then apply the unwrap operator?

Comment: Is there a sample image that you could add to your question?